# Websocket connection to ws://localhost:8000/ws/jobs/<job_id> failed

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, async-await, channel

I am trying to connect to the websocket using django and I'm still getting same connection error. I've checked the documents and using the same code from the tutorial.

```
const jobSocket = new WebSocket(
    "ws{% if request.get_host != 'localhost:8000' %}s{% endif %}://" + window.location.host + "/ws/jobs/{{ job.id }}/"
  );

  // Execute this function whenever this page receives an event from Job Consumer via WebSocket
  jobSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    var job = data.job;
    console.log(job);
```

l've tried using routing.py and asgi.py to access the path but the error is still the same "raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'ws/jobs/c5d1cc51-c2ad-458e-9cc7-f62520009112/'."

I've tried different url patterns, different regrex esspresion and no luck.

I tried this create a wair function to see if the websocket would open but it never does.

```
  function waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback){
    setTimeout(
        function () {
            if (socket.readyState === 1) {
                console.log("Connection is made")
                if (callback != null){
                    callback();
                }
            } else {
                console.log("wait for connection...")
                waitForSocketConnection(socket, callback);
            }

        }, 10); // wait 5 milisecond for the connection...
}
  
  function updateCourierPosition(map) {

    let url = `ws://${window.location.host}/ws/jobs/{{ job.id }}/`
    const jobSocket = new WebSocket(url)

    waitForSocketConnection(jobSocket,function() {
      jobSocket.onopen = function(event){
        jobSocket.send("connect")
        console.log("connect");
      };
    })
```

asgi.py

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
        ),
    }
)
```

urls.py

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/jobs/<job_id>', consumers.JobConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

consumer.py

```
class JobConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
  def connect(self):
    self.job_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['job_id']
    self.job_group_name = 'job_%s' % self.job_id

    # Join room group
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
      self.job_group_name,
      self.channel_name
    )

    self.accept()

  async def disconnect(self, close_code):
    # Leave room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)
   
    
  async def receive(self, text_data):
    text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
    job = text_data_json['job']

    print("Job", job)
```

Any help or assistance is appreciated.

Comment: try <int:job_id> i see that when you create the url you use {{ job.id }} and that id is an integer

Comment: No luck originally it was uuid and I changed it to INT to see if that would fix the issue but back to the drawing board.